# Why have a Request Model?

Tags: clean-architecture

What is the rationale for creating a Request Model object and passing it to the Interactor?

Why not just pass the data in as arguments and skip the allocation? It seems like a pretty short-lived object to me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Uncle Bobs book "Clean Architecture":

> The use case class accepts simple request data structures for its input, and returns simple response data structures as its output. These data structures are not dependent on anything. They do not derive from standard framework interfaces such as HttpRequest and HttpResponse. They know nothing of the web, nor do they share any of the trappings of whatever user interface might be in place.

The key aspect is that the "request data structures" (notice the "s") are independent and simple data structures. It is not necessary to create a dedicated request model type for each interactor as long as the data structures you pass to an interactor are primitives of your programming language/environment (e.g. .Net or Java) or you have defined those in the use case layer.

Answer (score 3):

I use request model for validating input values in "first view" - int values is int values, string no longer than 5 chars and so on. 
So it's takes main responsibility: dummy(types) checks and conversations.

Also requests helps with group many input values in one block. 
For response I come to just structures that have optional for"payload" (expected response) and many flags about errors. First time I tempted to put error objects (of course from use case layer) but come to issue: that issues need to be converted for actual view implementation, language. With flags I have sign about concrete issues, that can happens in use case, and I know that I should implement processing for them.

Comment: UPD: also, try no tempt to put all validation and parsing input data in request model. We get stuck with this, and not, our business layer has UseCaseRequest, that knows about Django! =) We need to read files from django-request object, we do this in request model - i think it's not good. 
Now we moving our parsing in separate functions, that returns this UseCaseRequest. and this functions declared on outer layers - where we know all about django, web and so on.